GeoServer is not running as administrator after reinstalling it

I installed GeoServer, then it was not working on localhost8080. Then I uninstalled it and reinstalled. But now GeoServer is not running as administrator and this messages keeps coming on my laptop:

GeoServer has already been installed in your system.
Please remove that version if you wish to update or re-install.

I don't understand it. I have uninstalled it and have removed all the residual files and so. I am unable to proceed the re-installation process. What should I do?

I just experienced that. Removing the following Key in the Windows Registry Editor solved the issue:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\GeoServer

